# Radio button validation using template driven forms and NgFor in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Could someone please explain me why when trying to validate a radio button without using NgFor for the options works:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'rio-app',
  template: `
    <form #myForm="ngForm">

      <label>
        Male: 
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" 
          ngModel required #gender="ngModel"
        />
      </label>

      <label>
        Female: 
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" 
          ngModel required #gender="ngModel"
        />
      </label>

      <div [hidden]="!gender.hasError('required')">
        The gender is required
      </div>

    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ckmuLuaOJjEQKc2Mu9a7?p=preview)

But if I try to do the same thing using `NgFor` it fails:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'rio-app',
  template: `
    <form #myForm="ngForm">

      <label *ngFor="let gender of genders">
        {{ gender }}: 
        <input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" 
          ngModel required #myGender="ngModel"
        />
      </label>

      <div [hidden]="!myGender.hasError('required')">
        The gender is required
      </div>

    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  genders = ['Male', 'Female']
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GQLfWjIziR0oteFSwCQT?p=preview)

I'm getting an error message in the browser's console that says:

`Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up opening an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13974) in the Angular repo and one person (@alexzuza) gave me a good answer that I want to share with you for future references:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rio-app',
  template: `
    <form #myForm="ngForm">

      <input type="text" />

      <ng-container *ngFor="let gender of genders; let isLast = last">

        <label>
          {{ gender }}: 
          <input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" 
            ngModel required #myGender="ngModel"
          />
        </label>

        <div *ngIf="isLast" [hidden]="!myGender.hasError('required')">
          The gender is required
        </div>

      </ng-container>

    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  genders = ['Male', 'Female']
}
```

To my understanding, the trick is to do everything inside of the `NgFor` using the `<ng-container>` because every variable created inside the loop will have block scope.

Here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ufRNSFV9EYeBmyItaF6Q)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at that second plunker it seems that the template reference variable `#myGender` defined within the `*ngFor` isn't visible outside i.e. in that error message `div`.

But you do have access at that level to `#myForm` though, so you can use that to check for errors on the gender FormControl.

```
<div [hidden]="!myForm.controls.gender?.hasError('required')">
    The gender is required
</div>
```

From the Angular doco I knew that the gender variable defined in the `*ngFor` definition wouldn't be visible but I wasn't sure about template variables within that block. Someone else might provide us with a better explanation of that.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, I might use it for now but this might be an Angular bug. I might open an issue in their repo

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why 'myGender' is undefined and I have no idea how to solve this issue with the normal FormsModule to be completely honest with you, i know how you can solve this with the 'ReactiveFormsModule' though.

In your AppModule you have to change the Forms module import from

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

to

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And change the import in your @NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

You'll have to import some new things in your component now

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

And you'll have to change your form a little bit for the ReactiveFormsModule

```
  <label *ngFor="let gender of genders">
    {{ gender }}: 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" 
       required [formControl]="myForm.controls['gender']"
    />
  </label>

  <div [hidden]="!myForm.controls['gender'].hasError('required')">
    The gender is required
  </div>

</form>
```

Now you can use the form builder to define your form controls and validators

```
export class AppComponent {
  genders = ['Male', 'Female'];
  myForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'gender' : [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

This is the only way I now of to work around this issue if you really want to use a for loop.

Edit:

[Plnkr example](https://embed.plnkr.co/pQrIseT4JKs81lelXEFd/)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Unfortunately I can't use the FormBuilder in this case because I'm using that piece of code to teach the principles of template driven forms with validation